# File extension shell verbs don't show up in Windows 10 context menus

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-shell

Shell verbs for the `.AHK` extension:

- Don't show up in Explorer context menus
- Don't work when launching the process programmatically

I've confirmed that:

- They're in the correct registry key
- `.ahk` is set to use that registry key

[image: .ahk registry key]

[image: AutoHotkeyScript registry key]

[image: .ahk context menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileExts` registry key was overriding the other key.

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`.
3. Delete the `.ahk` key.

   [image: The .ahk key inside the FileExts key in Registry Editor]

Now the correct shell verbs show up.

[image: .ahk context menu with correct shell verbs]

Comment: This saved me a BUNCH of time, apparently the .SLN was getting overridden also, can you tell me how you were able to narrow it down to this FileExts Registry key, was there an MSDN Document you found?

Comment: @aolszowka Can't remember...I think it was a registry search. Glad it helped.

Comment: @Bobort Fixed, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: This fix worked for me temporarily (I am trying to add a new context menu item for PNG files under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.png`). After exporting & deleting the `.png` Key under `FileExts` I saw my custom entry in the context menu, but the `.png` Key under `FileExts` reappeared as soon as I right-clicked a PNG file.

There seem to be a few alternatives, but the new context menu item works better for me when I put it under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations`.

Answer (score 2):

To create extension-specific context menu entries that will be displayed regardless of the `FileExt > PrgID` association and/or the `HKCU\...\Explorer\FileExts\<.ext>\UserChoice` values, create your entry under:

```
     `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\<.ext>`
```

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\Shell\MyCommand]
@="NewMenuVerb"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\Shell\MyCommand\Command]
@="Notepad \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@Eric Eskildsen](https://superuser.com/users/467894/eric-eskildsen)'s answer:
If this is causing the problems, you want to add your commands to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\XXX.XXX\shell\...`.
 E.g.: Your file type is associated with notepad.exe. You would add your commands to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell\...`